# Recieving very slow response from twitter usertimeline requests, is the twitter API slow?

Tags: api, rest, drupal, twitter

I am retrieving tweets from multiple accounts (around 20) and displaying them on a page. The request are very slow and my page takes one to two minutes to load. I am using the twitteroauth library (PHP). If i reduce the number of accounts, the loading time kind of decreases.

Here's the function

```
//twitter credentials and connection
$consumer_key = variable_get('tw_consumer_key', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'); //consumer key
$consumer_secret = variable_get('tw_consumer_secret', 'xxxxxxx'); // consumer secret
$oauth_token = variable_get('tw_access_token', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'); //oAuth Token
$oauth_token_secret = variable_get('tw_access_token_secret', 'xxxxxxxxxx'); //oAuth Token Secret

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";


//Retrieve feeds now
foreach ($twitter_accounts as $account_twitter) {
    if (!empty($account_twitter['lien'])) {
        $page_url = $account_twitter['lien'];
        $twitter_name = $account_twitter['compte'];

        $query = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' . $twitter_name . '&exclude_replies=true&include_rts=true&include_entities=true';

        $content = $connection->get($query);

        if (sizeof($content) > 0 && empty($content->errors)) {
            $tw_tweets['posts'] = $content;
            $tw_tweets['url'] = $page_url;
            $twitter_feeds[] = $tw_tweets;
        }//end if sizeof
        else {
            if (!empty($content->errors)) {
                $error = '';
                $error = (isset($content->errors[0]->message)) ? $content->errors[0]->message : '';
                $error .= (isset($content->errors[0]->code)) ? ' code' . $content->errors[0]->code : '';
                watchdog('ffbb_hubsocial', 'Twitter Account ' . $account_twitter['compte'] . ' failed to return results :' . $error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the API slow ?
Anyone knows if the problem is with twitter ?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question:  [Why are the Twitter api calls so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690752/why-are-the-twitter-api-calls-so-slow)

As the above answer states, try testing the URL in your browser and see how long it takes. Hence, you'll be able to see if the issue is on your side or due to Twitter.

Comment: I can't really test directly with the browser since the api changed to version 1.1